# Trade anything?

Tags: hedging, asset-pricing, market-making, financial-markets, betting

I have a question after reading the post below.
https://www.onlinebetting.org.uk/betting-guides/can-you-bet-on-anything-you-want.html

Question:
I want to bet on a niche topic or asset or anything that is not already traded anywhere else.
Example:**I want to bet that country X would ban a certain substance Y in 2022?**

Are there corp/entities that welcome bets on any topic/asset? The corp/entities decide if they want to take the other side of the bet or not. If they like my bet, they propose a market structure to me including the commissions, odds, minimum staked amount, and the other terms of the bet. If I am fine with the market structure, then they would make the market for me.

A term on the bet could be to restrict trading in and out of the bet once it is purchased by me. That means I must always wait for the bet to expire, and can not sell my bet prior. In this scenario, it makes it easier for the market maker to avoid unnecessary hedging. I am fine with such a condition.

*The market is similar to an OTC. However, OTC is not opened to everyone except institutional investors, who can trade on OTC. Also, OTC is primarily for financial derivatives and not for random bets on a substance Y.*

Comment: i may know people who would take the trade...email me

Comment: Alright, but that example in the question is not my current interest, just a random example. I need people/companies that would consider any random trade idea in general. Of course, they must not accept all ideas, but at least take a look at those ideas to see if they can offer a market. Anyways, would email you.

Answer (score 0):

Is your trade on a liquid financial instrument; or is "related" to markets  with idiosyncratic (and thus unhedgeable) funnies??? That makes a huge difference to the prices/odds/spread-differentials offered...

SOP is to simplify the complex into the closest approximating liquid options...